# Angular2 load children module issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i have try load to children module in angular2/4 routing but i got Error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module
>   '../market-place/market-place.module'.

i have tried the below code parent routing **discover.routing.ts**:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const DiscoverRoutes: Routes = [
    // part of MarketPlace
    {
        path: 'market-place', loadChildren: '../market-place/market-place.module#MarketPlaceModule',
    }
]
export const DiscoversRoutes = RouterModule.forChild(DiscoverRoutes);
```

**in html:**

```
<a [routerLink]=" ['discoverd/market-place'] ">Market place</a>
```

**Folder tree:**
[image: foldertree]

Updated

**parent module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DiscoversRoutes } from './discover.routing';
import { DiscoverComponent } from './discover.component'
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DiscoversRoutes
    ],
    declarations: [
        DiscoverComponent

   ],
})
export class DiscoverModule { }
```

child routing module

```
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'vendors', pathMatch: 'full' },
        {
            path: '',
            component: MarketPlaceComponent,
            children: [
                { // Vendors selection
                    path: 'vendors',
                    component: MpVendorSelectionComponent,
                    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
                    resolve: { partner: PartnerResolver },
                    data: { roles: ['products.list_vendordetails'] }
                }]
    }}
export const MarketPlaceRouting = RouterModule.forChild(MarketPlaceRoutes);
```

**child module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MarketPlaceRouting } from './market-place.routing';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';// Components
import { MarketPlaceComponent } from './market-place.component';
import { MpVendorSelectionComponent } from './mp-vendor-selection/mp-vendor-selection.component';
import { MpProductsSelectionComponent } from './mp-products-selection/mp-products-selection.component';
import { MpProductsListComponent } from './mp-products-selection/mp-products-list/mp-products-list.component';
import { MpProductViewComponent } from './mp-products-selection/mp-product-view/mp-product-view.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    MarketPlaceRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    MarketPlaceComponent,
    MpVendorSelectionComponent,
    MpProductsSelectionComponent,
    MpProductsListComponent,
    MpProductViewComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class MarketPlaceModule { }
```

Thanks in advnace

Comment: can u show parent routing module and child routing module

Comment: @JinsPeter check my updated code

Comment: I meant parent routing module. you have multiple routing modules i assume??

Comment: @JinsPeter this is my parent routing module "discover.routing.ts"

Comment: I don't get it is there something incomplete in the code, ? check the part right after "export class DiscoverModule { }" is it comment or code

Comment: @JinsPeter do you have any sample using relative path specification "../"

Comment: I did not use relative path i used 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule', admin being my module name which is inside app module

Comment: Does it work removing the relative path from the `loadChildren`?

Comment: @axl-code Yes its working

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6632 hope it helps